# How to swap Z & Y keys on QWERTZ keyboard but keep everything else as it is?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I want to **swap Z & Y keys on QWERTZ layout German keyboard** but I prefer keeping everything else pretty much as it is.

I’m fine with the German keyboard, but I’ve always used QWERTY and so very used to <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> within an easy reach, considering I use that shortcut every day, I mean overuse, to be exact.

I downloaded the Ukulele app, but a few settings were a little unclear as someone kind of unfamiliar with remapping the keyboard. I couldn’t find the exact answer to what I wanted to do, there were similar questions but some specific differences in terms of additional stuff other than what I needed. I tried but I don’t really want to mess with the whole thing, in case I do something slightly different.

To make it clear, I would prefer also swapping all the other options at the same time, for those two specific keys, like when used together with <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Opt</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd> kind of full package swap between <kbd>Z</kbd> & Y.

Anyone can help me with it?

Comment: Are you using the input source called "German standard"?

Comment: @Tetsujin  this poster wants German qwerty on mac, that poster wanted English qwertz on windows.  It's normally a few minutes with ukelele,but German and German Standard have different option layers.

Comment: @TomGewecke - ah, my bad. I read the two questions within minutes of each other & had incorrectly assumed they were linked.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this one](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n64v5f0m83gkn1j/German%20qwerty.bundle.zip?dl=0) done with Ukelele.

Comment: I'm sure the material at the link you have provided is quite helpful and perhaps self explanatory to anyone who knows "Ukelele" to some extent but perhaps just a bit more explanation with your answer would be nicer.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it without 3-rd party software using built-in `hidutil` tool. I've already answered [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/453786/484998).

**TL;DR**: for simple key remapping for MacOS you could use [hidutil-generator](https://hidutil-generator.netlify.app/) web-app.

From `hidutil`'s [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2450/_index.html):

> Keys can be remapped via the command-line tool hidutil. For example, use the hidutil command-line tool to remap the 'A' key to the 'B' key as shown in Listing 1. The map array consists of two key/value pairs that contain the source (HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc) and destination (HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDstKey) of the key remapping. The keys take a hexadecimal value that consists of 0x700000000 or’d with the desired keyboard usage value (see Table 1 for usage values).

```
$ hidutil property --set '{"UserKeyMapping":[{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x700000004,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x700000005},{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x700000005,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x700000004}]}'
```

> Key remappings are lost when the system is restarted or if the keyboard service is removed (for example when the last keyboard is disconnected.)

In your case you need to swap `Y` (`0x1C`) and `Z` (`0x1D`) but I'm not sure that codes are the same for German keyboard:

```
$ hidutil property --set '{"UserKeyMapping":[{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x70000001C,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x70000001D},{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x70000001D,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x70000001C}]}'
```

To prevent losing your changes, you could use custom [LaunchAgent](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html) to run your custom `hidutil` command on login.

There is [hidutil-generator](https://hidutil-generator.netlify.app/) web-app to generate a `.plist` file with your custom key remapping. Create your custom key remapping in the generator's form and copy resulting `.plist` file to your system.

Comment: If yoiu have the same answer elsewhere you should not answer here with just a link but flag the question as a duplicate,

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/332296)

Comment: @mmmmmm I've updated the answer with full description.

Comment: @IlyaRodionov No repeating the information from the other question does not make this a good answer

Comment: @mmmmmm I've provided full description of how to do it and changed the example code to match the asked question. How can I make the answer more useful?

Comment: @IlyaRodionov You can't as the answer is the same as the duplicate so this question should be closed and readers directed to the other. The other answer might be improved by moving up the generator information as you did here. If one answer is mainly a cut and paste of another then there is something wrong,