# <> and ^° keys switched on Satechi compact backlit USB keyboard

Tags: macos, keyboard, karabiner, dock

Using a Satechi Compact Backlit USB keyboard QWERTZ variant: https://satechi.net/products/compact-backlit-bluetooth-keyboard

It is a nice product however < > and ^ ° keys are switched. Did a firmware update for the keyboard in the hope that may fix the problem but issue is persisting. This is a problem on macOS 13 + 12.

1. would this be solvable for the vendor? I am really confused this is sold for macOS and then keys are not behaving as expected.
2. Karabiner Elements could probably fix this.

[image: The switched keys]

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without 3-rd party software using built-in `hidutil` tool.

**TL;DR**: just use [hidutil-generator](https://hidutil-generator.netlify.app/)

From [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2450/_index.html):

> Keys can be remapped via the command-line tool hidutil. For example, use the hidutil command-line tool to remap the 'A' key to the 'B' key as shown in Listing 1. The map array consists of two key/value pairs that contain the source (HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc) and destination (HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDstKey) of the key remapping. The keys take a hexadecimal value that consists of 0x700000000 or’d with the desired keyboard usage value (see Table 1 for usage values).

```
$ hidutil property --set '{"UserKeyMapping":[{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x700000004,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x700000005},{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x700000005,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x700000004}]}'
```

> Key remappings are lost when the system is restarted or if the keyboard service is removed (for example when the last keyboard is disconnected.)

In your case you need to swap `grave_accent_and_tilde` (`0x35`) with `non_us_backslash` (`0x64`):

```
$ hidutil property --set '{"UserKeyMapping":[{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x700000035,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x700000064},{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x700000064,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x700000035}]}'
```

To prevent losing your changes, you could use custom [LaunchAgent](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html) to run your custom `hidutil` command on login.

There is [hidutil-generator](https://hidutil-generator.netlify.app/) web-app to generate a `.plist` file with your custom key remapping. Create your custom key remapping in the generator's form and copy resulting `.plist` file to your system.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround in Karabiner Element as follows, which works fine:

[image: Karabiner Elements > Simple Modifications cross-assign grav_accent_and_tilde with non_us_backslash]